# Laravel Collection macro not found in phpunit unit test?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-collection, laravel-testing, laravel-unit-test

I'm running a unit test in Laravel in phpunit and encountering this error where my Collection macro seemingly does not exist:

> `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getNext does not exist.`

The code itself works absolutely fine in the project, though! The line which fails here has been exercised in "production" a whole lot and is without issue. This problem *only* seems to exist when testing with phpunit.

**Here's where I define the macro:**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        /**
         * Returns the next found item in the collection after the given index value
         */
        Collection::macro('getNext', function ($currentIndex) {
            return $this->get($currentIndex + 1, null);
        });
    }
}
```

**And the test code:**

```
namespace Tests\Feature;
use App\src\LineProcessLibrary;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class LineProcessLibraryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_process_stuff(): void
    {
        $input = [
            ['text' => 'This line continues,', 'start' => 10, 'end' => 12]
        ];

        $res = LineProcessLibrary::processStuff($input);
    }
```

**And the actual code being invoked:**

```
namespace App\src;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class LineProcessLibrary
{
    public static function processStuff($list)
    {
        $stuff = collect($list);
        foreach ($stuff as $key => $curr) {

            $next = $stuff->getNext($key);
            dd($next);
        }
    }
```

So far I've tried moving the test to the `Feature` folder and namespace in the hope that stuff there has more app related classes automatically loaded (including hopefully my macro). No luck so far.

This really seems like the sort of thing that could be a common issue or should really have a simple, well-known fix but so far I can't find it.

Comment: Which `TestCase` (full namespace) is your test class extending?

Comment: use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

Comment: that is your error, you have to extend the one that the Feature tests extended, else you never have Laravel loaded

Comment: I swapped to `use Tests\TestCase;` in the Feature test and this works! Brilliant! I had missed doing this because this started as a unit test that I moved manually to Feature and missed this. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Laravel understands `Unit` tests as literal Unit tests (Laravel never gets instantiated), but most devs (I assume based on my experience) understands `Unit` tests as standalone classes (for example, a job, a listener, but also classes that have nothing to do with Laravel, like a domain class, etc), and we test something from it. But you must extend `\Tests\TestCase` so Laravel gets instantiated

Answer (score 2):

Laravel docs says:

> Typically, you should declare collection macros in the boot method of a service provider.

So i would move the the macro from register to boot

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it doesn't solve the problem. Still the same thing.

Comment: have you tried ```php artisan optimize:clear``` ?

Comment: @suxgri it does not make a difference here because when the test starts, Laravel has fully run (it run `register` and `boot`, so the macro is declared)